# Unable to edit form fields in Reactjs after fetched from server

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I have a user edit page in Reactjs where I fetch the user details and populate it to corresponding input fields. The problem is after fetching and displaying the data I'm not able to edit the fields.

My code is:

```
function EditProfile(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
            const profileConfig = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.token
                }
            };
            fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/user/me`, profileConfig)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log("response: ", response.user);
                if (response.success === true) {
                    setUser(response.user)
                } else {
                    alert(response.message)
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                alert('User fetching faied: ' + error)
            })
        }
        fetchUserInfo()
    }, [])

    return (
       <form>
           <input type="text" value={user.name} name="name" />
       </form>
    )
}
```

The corresponding name is displayed in this input field but not editable. How to solve the issue?

Comment: add `onChange` handler

Comment: @Vaibhav But I'm fetching the values from user object. How to update it onChange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not added `onChange` function on your `input` which React recommends to make it a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). The advantages of having a controlled input is that you have the value available throughout you React component and you do not need an event to be fired on input or access the DOM to get the value.

If you don't want to create a controlled component you do it this way:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={user.name} name="name" />
```

Using `defaultValue` instead of `value`. Because in the React rendering lifecycle, the value attribute on form elements will override the value in the DOM. With this you want React to specify the initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled hence creating an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).

If you create a controlled component you will have to specify a function to handle the change and set that to the state as specified by this answer below by @Vaibhav: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133180/4207394

Answer (score 2):

In React controlled component needs value & change handler.

```
function EditProfile(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ''})

    useEffect(() => {
        /*
          ....
        */
    }, [])

    const handleChange = e => {
       setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})
    }

    return (
       <form>
           <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={user.name} name="name" />
       </form>
    )
}
```